# Flask-WTF set time limit on CSRF token

Tags: python, flask, csrf, flask-wtforms

I'm currently using Flask-WTF v0.13.1, i have a few forms on my website, all created including the CSRF token.

For some reasons i have to set a different expiration on each form, so far i could set manually the `time_limit` value upon creating the csrf token.

I would like to update to the v0.14, according to the [changelog](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/master/docs/changelog.rst#version-014) `time_limit` is gone and there is no reference in the docs on how to change it anymore. 
Looking in the source code i saw that the form has a `csrf_time_limit` meta parameter.

I tried to set that parameter on my form:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm

class myForm(FlaskForm):
    class Meta:
        csrf_time_limit = 7200

    content = TextAreaField('content')
```

Although debugging the `csrf.py` [module](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/master/flask_wtf/csrf.py) i see that the `validate_csrf_token` of `_FlaskFormCSRF` is actually never called.

The method `validate_csrf` is called within the method `protect()` instead, in this case the meta parameter is never considered.

I don't understand if this is a bug of the package or if i'm missing something.

UPDATE:

Example code:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import IntegerField

csrf = CSRFProtect()
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(dict(
    SECRET_KEY="super secret key"
))

csrf.init_app(app)

class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    class Meta:
        csrf_time_limit = 1

    id = IntegerField('id')

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test_form_csrf():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        myForm = MyForm(request.form)
        print(myForm.id.data)

    return render_template('test_form.html', myForm= MyForm())
```

templates/test_form.html

```
<form method="post" action="/">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    {{ myForm.id }}
    <input type="submit" value="test" />
</form>
```

requirements.txt

```
click==6.7
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
WTForms==2.1
```

project structure

```
app.py
templates
|
--- test_form.html
```

To run the code,

```
FLASK_APP=app.py flask run
```

I also put a debug breakpoint on [this line](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/master/flask_wtf/csrf.py#L99) to check the actual value of `time_limit`, the value is always `3600`.

Answer (score 12):

Following your [changelog](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/master/docs/changelog.rst#version-014) link, I looked through the commit and found [these lines](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/pull/264/commits/ce17638bf47c8ee0f9298d903479a3603e2c54a5#diff-0d3586b054b671fbe3d21309518f6353L86):

```
if time_limit is None:
    time_limit = current_app.config.get('WTF_CSRF_TIME_LIMIT', 3600)
```

Setting `app.config['WTF_CSRF_TIME_LIMIT']` to some shorter value seems to work. I have set it to 30 seconds with `app.config['WTF_CSRF_TIME_LIMIT'] = 30` and the form expired after that amount of time, but I have not tried a longer value than the default.

I am not sure if you can change an app.config value on the fly in order to hack your way around not being able to set an expiration per form.

Comment: I can confirm that setting `WTF_CSRF_TIME_LIMIT` in the config object still works when using `Flask-WTF==0.14.2` and `WTForms==2.2.1`. I can see the original question is 1.5 yrs old at this time, so I thought it'd be a good idea to leave this quick update here.